# Rationals are a subset of union of countable set of intervals

Tags: real-analysis

For every $\epsilon>0$, prove there exists a countable set of intervals

$I_n \subset \Bbb R$ such that
$\Bbb Q ⊂\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty
I_n$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\text{diam}(I_n)} < \epsilon.$$

I am currently enrolled in an introductory proof writing class, and I genuinely have no idea how to even begin thinking about or writing a proof for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can show that this is true for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\text{diam}(I_n)} < 1$, the easy thing to do is to scale all of these intervals by a factor of $\epsilon$. Can you come up with a sequence of diameters $\{d_1, d_2, \dots\}$ that sums to $1$? Then, since the rationals are countable, enumerate them $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n, \dots\}$ and construct the intervals $I_n$ such that each $x_n$ is contained in an interval of size $d_n$.

Comment: The geometric series starting with 1/2 sums up to 1. Could you please tell me how to write what you said to do? I understand that if I succeed in doing so, I would have each rational is in some interval, the diameters of all these intervals sum up to 1, which proves that rationals are a subset of these intervals and by scaling down, I can also satisfy the second property. But how do I write what you said in "math" form? (Sorry for my lack of being able to explain myself)

Comment: You can construct the intervals explicitly. This should be enough for you to justify that the desired properties are indeed satisfied in "math" form (if you have the intervals, you can sum the diameters, and you can show $\mathbb{Q} \subset \bigcup I_n$).

Comment: But that what I'm saying is that I do not know how to construct the intervals.

Comment: If I give you a number $d_1$ and a number $x_1$, can you construct an interval containing $x_1$ with diameter $d_1$? If this is too abstract, plug in actual numbers: can you construct an interval of diameter $0.5$ which contains $\pi$? If you can generalize this strategy, this gives you the intervals.

Comment: IT CLICKED! Thank you so much!